# grep .* listing giving unnecessary results! how to handle?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Why are `baseline.config.total.no.1of.banner=a_1` and `baseline.config.total.no.2of.banner=b_2` included in output? Shouldn't `baseline.config.total.no..*.` require one dot between `1of` and `2of`?

```
$ grep "baseline.config.total.no..*." ./output/messages_en.properties
baseline.config.total.no.1of.banner=a_1
baseline.config.total.no.2of.banner=b_2
baseline.config.total.no.1.of.banner=10-1streak
```

Comment: `.` means "match anything", not just a dot -- that's *why* `.*` means "match anything, any number of times".

Comment: ...that said, I actually don't see why you think this regex would *require one dot between `1of` and `2of`*. A `.*` matches *anything*, after all, including any number of dots.

Answer (score 5):

`.` matches anything, not just a dot; that (and `*` meaning "match the last thing 0-or-more times") is *why* `.*` means "match anything, zero-or-more times".

Consequently, the regex `baseline.config` will also match the string `baseline-config`, or the string `baselineoconfig` -- the dot is *always* a wildcard when not escaped or in a character class.

Since you want to have dots that only match dots, consider `[.]` -- creating a single-character character class. This is more reliable (less sensitive to quoting context) than `\.`, the other alternative.

```
grep 'baseline[.]config[.]total[.]no[.].*[.]'
```